# How do I use zoom with a MonadState constraint of a newtype?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I have two functions, one with a MonadState constraint of the wrapped type, the other has a MonadState constraint of the unwrapped type. I'd like to seamlessly run the second function within the first.

For example:

```
import qualified Control.Monad.State.Strict as MTL
import Data.Monoid (Sum)
import Control.Lens.Zoom (zoom)
import Control.Lens.Wrapped (_Wrapped')

outer :: (MTL.MonadState (Sum Int) m) => m Int
outer = zoom _Wrapped' inner

inner :: (MTL.MonadState Int m) => m Int
inner = MTL.get
```

The above seems to me like it should work, yet I get 3 type checker errors. The first:

```
Could not deduce (Control.Lens.Zoom.Zoom m0 m Int (Sum Int))
  arising from a use of ‘zoom’
from the context (MTL.MonadState (Sum Int) m)
  bound by the type signature for
             outer :: MTL.MonadState (Sum Int) m => m Int
The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous
```

From my searching, I get the impression that `zoom` can't do what I want. (found this quote on http://ircbrowse.net/browse/haskell "reltuk: yeah, thats the unfortunate downside of lenses is that zooming forces you to a concrete state monad") I guess that lines up with the error message stating that "m0 is ambiguous".

I'd really rather not change my MonadState constraint into a concrete monad.

Is there some other standard way of doing what I want?

## Edit:

This will not type check:

```
sumOuter :: (Functor (Zoomed m Int),
           Zoom m m Int t,
           Wrapped t,
           Unwrapped t ~ Int,
           MTL.MonadState (Sum Int) m) => m Int
sumOuter = zoom _Wrapped' sumInner

sumInner :: (MTL.MonadState Int m) => m Int
sumInner = MTL.get
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zoom` has its own class for overloading, so no wonder just `MonadState` doesn't cut it. The [`Zoom`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.11/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html#t:Zoom) class covers roughly the same ground as `mtl`, although it has somewhat more complicated machinery. In any case, you're not obligated to program in concrete monads.

You can try enabling `NoMonomorphismRestriction` and inferring a type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import Control.Lens.Internal.Zoom
import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Monoid
import Control.Monad.Except -- for illustration

outer = zoom _Wrapped' get
```

Now `:t outer` gives

```
outer :: 
  (Functor (Zoomed m (Unwrapped t)), Zoom m n (Unwrapped t) t, Wrapped t) 
  => n (Unwrapped t)
```

This isn't pretty, but it seems to work.

```
> runState outer (Sum 10)
(10, Sum {getSum = 10})
> runState (runExceptT outer) (Sum 10) :: (Either String Int, Sum Int)
(Right 10,Sum {getSum = 10})
```

EDIT:

If you really want to specialize to `Sum Int` as the outer state, and also want to have `MonadState (Sum Int) n` constraint, this suffices:

```
sumOuter ::
  (Functor (Zoomed m Int), Zoom m n Int (Sum Int)) => n Int
sumOuter = zoom _Wrapped' sumInner

sumInner :: (MTL.MonadState Int m) => m Int
sumInner = MTL.get
```

What about the `MonadState` constraint? There's no need to write it out, because `Zoom m n s t` has `MonadState s m` and `MonadState t n` as superclasses.

Likewise, the more general `outer` function already implies `MonadState t n`.

Comment: I see that your examples work (runState outer (Sum 10)). See my edit. Why won't that type check? I really do want a MonadState constraint (of Sum, not Int) on my outer function.